# Two-column output of setdiff() in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

My work is with proteomics analysis, and I'm using R for the first time.

So my input is in `.txt` and is a list of protein names, as I use the `setdiff()` function in a specific set of data instead of giving me a single column of proteins is giving me a double-column output. This didn't happen when I did the same thing with other data sets.

I already tried to look for a solution online and in R help but I couldn't find the same situation.

My lines are:

```
v1 <- readLines("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\V4\\Duo\\ECC_CC.txt")
v2 <- readLines("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\V4\\Duo\\ECC_CSC.txt") 
vlist <- list(v1, v2) 
names(vlist) <- c("Cell Line", "CSC") 
setdiff(v1, v2)
```

I even tried to switch the order on the input and edit the `.txt` files to see if the problem was with them.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  If you can try to provide a minimal reproducible example it will make it much easier to assist you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide us with the output of `dput(v1)` and `dput(v2)` or try to create similar vectors reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to R and Stack Overflow!

First of all, the `setdiff()` function calculates the asymmetric set difference of two vectors, according to its documentation (you can see this by doing `?base::setdiff` on the R console).

If you take a look into the examples, you will see that there is no need to put the dataframes into a list. You can just directly apply the `setdiff()` function to see which elements of **x** don't appear in **y**:

```
x <- c(sort(sample(1:20, 9)), NA)
y <- c(sort(sample(3:23, 7)), NA)
setdiff(x, y)
```

Or, in another example with the *mtcars* data, if you are working with dataframes (which is your case), you can just directly apply the `setdiff()` function to see which elements of **mtcars** don't appear in **mtcars2**:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars[-1,]
setdiff(mtcars, mtcars2)
```

So, once you make sure that both **v1** and **v2** dataframes contain the same variables, you could try to do this:

```
v1 <- readLines("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\V4\\Duo\\ECC_CC.txt")
v2 <- readLines("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Documents\\V4\\Duo\\ECC_CSC.txt") 
setdiff(v1, v2)
```

You could also do it performing an outer join with the `merge` function, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right).

I hope that this helps you!